# Importing methods for a Python class

Tags: python, import, methods

I wonder if it's possible to keep methods for a Python class in a different file from the class definition, something like this:

`main_module.py:`

```
class Instrument(Object):
    # Some import statement?
    def __init__(self):
        self.flag = True
    def direct_method(self,arg1):
        self.external_method(arg1, arg2)
```

`to_import_from.py:`

```
def external_method(self, arg1, arg2):
    if self.flag:
        #doing something
#...many more methods
```

In my case, `to_import_from.py` is machine-generated, and contains many methods. I would rather not copy-paste these into main_module.py or import them one by one, but have them all recognized as methods of the Instrument class, just as if they had been defined there:

```
>>> instr = Instrument()
>>> instr.direct_method(arg1)
>>> instr.external_method(arg1, arg2)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Do you control the generation of to_import_from.py, or do you have to use it "as is"?

Comment: Yes, I can control it a bit by tweaking the code of ctypeslib.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't think what you want is directly possible in Python.

You could, however, try one of the following.

1. When generating `to_import_from.py`, add the non-generated stuff there too. This way,
   all methods are in the same class definition.
2. Have `to_import_from.py` contain a base class definition which the the Instrument class
   inherits.

In other words, in `to_import_from.py`:

```
class InstrumentBase(object):
    def external_method(self, arg1, arg2):
        if self.flag:
            ...
```

and then in `main_module.py`:

```
import to_import_from

class Instrument(to_import_from.InstrumentBase):
    def __init__(self):
        ...
```

Answer (score 20):

People seem to be overthinking this. Methods are just function valued local variables in class construction scope. So the following works fine:

```
class Instrument(Object):
    # load external methods
    from to_import_from import *

    def __init__(self):
        self.flag = True
    def direct_method(self,arg1):
        self.external_method(arg1, arg2)
```

Comment: SyntaxWarning: import * only allowed at module level

Comment: To overcome the `SyntaxError` (Python 3.6) don't do `import *`. Instead, name the methods to import explicitly, e.g. `from to_import_from import method1, method2`.

Comment: Won't this be passed the class as the first variable when calling the external method?

Answer (score 8):

It's easier than you think:

```
class Instrument(Object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.flag = True
    def direct_method(self,arg1):
        self.external_method(arg1, arg2)

import to_import_from

Instrument.external_method = to_import_from.external_method
```

Done!

Although having the machine generated code generate a class definition and subclassing from it would be a neater solution.

Answer (score 5):

I'm sorry that this is kind of a ["You shouldn't be putting nails in the wall" answer](https://stackoverflow.fogbugz.com/default.asp?W29025), but you're missing the point of python class definitions. You should rather put the class with all its methods in its own python file, and in your `main_module.py` do

```
from instrument import Instrument
```

If you plan on using the methods for several classes, you should consider subclassing. In your case, the machine generated file could contain the base class that `Instrument` inherits from.

Finally, give your class a good docstring that explains the API to its user, so there is no need for a "header file" used as an overview of your class.

Answer (score 5):

you can do this with the `__getattr__` method

external.py

```
def external_function(arg):
    print("external", arg)
```

main.py:

```
import external

class Instrument(object):
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        if hasattr(external, name):
            return getattr(external, name)
        else:
            return Object.__getattr__(self, name)

    def direct_method(self, arg):
        print("internal", arg)


i = Instrument() 
i.direct_method("foo")
i.external_function("foo")
```

Answer (score 2):

What you're doing is extending a base class with some "machine-generated" code.

Choice 1.  Extend a base class with machine-generated code.

machine_generated.py

```
# Start of boilerplate #
import main_module
class Instrument_Implementation( main_module.Instrument_Abstraction ):
    def direct_method(self,arg1): 
       # End of boilerplate #
       ...the real code...
```

Your application can then `import machine_generated` and use `machine_generated.Instrument_Implementation`.

Choice 2.  Simply use first-class functions.

machine_generated.py

```
def external_method(self, arg1, arg2):
    ...the real code...
```

main_module.py

```
import machine_generated

class Instrument( object ):
    def direct_method(self,arg1): 
        return machine_generator.external_method( arg1, ... )
```

Your application can `import main_module` and use `main_module.Instrument`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my try. I think a nicer approach could be made with metaclasses...

to_import_from.py :

```
def external_method(self, arg1, arg2):
    if self.flag:
        print "flag is set"
    else :
        print "flag is not set"
```

instrument.py :

```
import imp
import os
import inspect
import new

import pdb

class MethodImporter(object) :
    def __init__(self, path_to_module) :
        self.load_module(path_to_module)

    def load_module(self, path_to_module) :
        name = os.path.basename(path_to_module)
        module_file = file(path_to_module,"r")
        self.module = imp.load_module(name, module_file , path_to_module, ('','r',imp.PY_SOURCE))
        print "Module %s imported" % self.module
        for method_name, method_object in inspect.getmembers(self.module, inspect.isfunction) :
            print "adding method %s to %s" % (method_name, self)
            setattr(self, method_name, new.instancemethod(method_object, self, self.__class__))


class Instrument(MethodImporter):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Instrument,self).__init__("./to_import_from.py")
        self.flag = True
    def direct_method(self,arg1):
        self.external_method(arg1, arg2)
```

when you run this code

```
arg1, arg2 = 1, 2
instr = Instrument()
instr.direct_method(arg1)
instr.external_method(arg1, arg2)
```

here's the output :

```
Module <module 'to_import_from.py' from './to_import_from.pyc'> imported
adding method external_method to <__main__.Instrument object at 0x2ddeb0>
flag is set
flag is set
```

Answer (score 0):

Technically, yes this is possible, but solving it this way is not really idiomatic python, and there are likely better solutions.  Here's an example of how to do so:

```
import to_import_from

class Instrument(object):
    locals().update(dict((k,v) for (k,v) in 
                    to_import_from.__dict__.iteritems() if callable(v)))

    def __init__(self):
        self.flag = True
    def direct_method(self,arg1):
        self.external_method(arg1, arg2)
```

That will import all callable functions defined in `to_import_from` as methods of the `Instrument` class, as well as adding some more methods.  Note: if you also want to copy global variables as instance variables, you'll need to refine the check.  Also note that it adds *all* callable objects it finds in to_import_from's namespace, including imports from other modules (ie `from module import some_func` style imports)

However, this isn't a terribly nice way to do it.  Better would be to instead tweak your code generation to *produce* a class, and have your class inherit from it.  This avoids the unneccessary copying of methods into Instrument's namespace, and instead uses normal inheritcance.  ie:

```
class Instrument(to_import_from.BaseClass):
    # Add new methods here.
```